# Commiting a java file update to git

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and stackoverflow.
I am having trouble updating my .java file on git.  Must be missing something minor. 
 Can you help.  Output is below?

```
bash-3.2$ git add bwt.java
bash-3.2$ git commit -m "new commit"
[master (root-commit) fc94e26] new commit
 1 file changed, 368 insertions(+)
 create mode 100755 src/bwtx/bwt.java
bash-3.2$ git remote add origin
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from

bash-3.2$ git remote add origin https://github.com/MartinRSchiller/BWT.git
bash-3.2$ git remote add origin 
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from
```

Comment: You've commited the file, added the remote `origin`. Now you should issue a `git push` command.

Comment: I actually dont see an error here - it looks like you just need to push the file as suggested below.  If the push fails, just post the output above and we can proceed looking into it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have successfully added the remote origin.  You should issue:

```
git push -u origin master
```

[I recommend looking at steps 1,2, and 3 in this github guide.](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo)

Comment: Thanks I thought it was simple.

Comment: New problem has to do with a merge

Comment: Before you push, it is a good idea to do a `git pull` as well.

Comment: You probably want `git push -u origin master` so it sets up `master` to follow `origin/master`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem seemed to be that my SSH key was ejected.  I do not know what I did to make this happen.

Comment: You need to setup ssh keys: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys